# this.xxxxx.subscribe is not a function

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm trying to subscribe to an Observable string but I do not understand the error message:

> this.templateName.subscribe is not a function

My code :

```
templateName: Observable<string>;

this.store.select(fromRoot.getRequestEntitiesState).subscribe(data => this.requestDetail = data)

this.templateName = this.requestDetail.request.templateName;

this.subscriptions.push(this.templateName.subscribe(templateName => {
  this.store.dispatch(new requestActions.LoadTemplateAction(templateName))
}))
```

Comment: `this.requestDetail.request.templateName` doesn't return an `Observable`

Comment: Ok thx u. How can i transform to an Observable ?

Comment: I don't know what `this.requestDetail.request.templateName;` is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.requestDetail.request.templateName
```

Should return an Observable.